# How can I test this angularjs filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I found this AngularJS unique filter example online: https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/angularjs/removing-duplicates-from-ng-repeat/

And I'm trying to test it. I'm really close but I'm getting an error that I don't understand why. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
describe('Unique Filter', function() {
  'use strict';

  var $filter;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('resource');

    inject(function (_$filter_) {
      $filter = _$filter_;
    });
  });

  it('should only return unique values', function() {
    var list = [
      { 'name' : "ipad" },
      { 'name' : "ipad" },
      { 'name' : "ipad" },
      { 'name' : "ipod" },
      { 'name' : "iMac" },
      { 'name' : "iMac" },
      { 'name' : "iMac" },
      { 'name' : "iPhone" },
      { 'name' : "iWatch" },
      { 'name' : "iWatch" },
      { 'name' : "iWatch" },
      { 'name' : "iPeed" }];

    var resultList = [
      { 'name' : "ipad" },
      { 'name' : "iMac" },
      { 'name' : "iPhone" },
      { 'name' : "iWatch" },
      { 'name' : "iPeed" }];

    var result = $filter('unique');
    expect(result(list)).toBe(resultList);
  });
});
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Unique Filter should only return unique values FAILED
    Expected [ Object({ name: 'ipad' }) ] to be [ Object({ name: 'ipad' }), Object({ name: 'iMac' }), Object({ name: 'iPhone' }), Object({ name: 'iWatch' }), Object({ name: 'iPeed' }) ].
    test/spec/resource/resource.filter.js:37:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As arbghl said, I was only returning one of the unique items, when I needed the whole array. Changing these two lines did the trick! I also was trying to do work on list where I shouldn't and I needed to pass in the parameters for the filter.

```
var result = $filter('unique')(list, 'name');
expect(result).toEqual(resultList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result, I can say your unique filter is returning just one object from the list rather than all the unique objects. May be you should look at the implementation of the filter again.

It expects a key of the array to filter with - 
`var result = $filter($scope.list)('unique')('name')`

Comment: Thank you. This isn't exactly right, but it helped me get there!